# strong induction case

Tags: induction

im stuck on this assignment. Can someone give me a hint?

Here is the assignment:
There are two types of creature on planet Char, Z-lings and B-lings.
Furthermore, every creature belongs to a particular generation. The creatures in each generation reproduce according to certain rules and then die off. The subsequent generationconsists entirely of their offspring.

The creatures of Char pair with a mate in order to reproduce. First, as many Z-B pairs as possible are formed. The remaining creatures form Z-Z pairs or B-B pairs, depending on whether there is an excess of Z-lings or of B-lings. If there are an odd number of creatures, then one in the majority species dies without reproducing.

The number and type of offspring
is determined by the types of the parents:

- If both parents are Z-lings, then they have three Z-ling offspring.
- If both parents are B-lings, then they have two B-ling offspring and one Z-ling offspring.
- If there is one parent of each type, then they have one offspring of each type.

There are 200 Z-lings and 800 B-lings in the first generation. Use induction to prove that the number of Z-lings will always be at most twice the number of B-lings.

Hint: You may want to use a stronger hypothesis for the induction

**My problem is that i always end upp with the same number of Z-lings as B-lings. The assignement however, requires me to prove the theorem that Z- lings can never be more than twice the B-lings.
What am i missing? Im basically doing a simple reproduce chart to figure out the pattern but i end wih the same end result, as mentioned..**

My chart

$$\begin{array}{ccccccccc}
 \text{Generation} & \text{Z-ling} & \text{B-ling} & \text{Z-B} & \text{Z-Z} & \text{B-B} & \text{Offs.B} & \text{Offs. Z} \\
   1 &  200  &   800   &   200  &    0  &  300  &  800   &    500  \\
   2 &  500  &   800   &   500  &    0  &  150  &  800   &    650 \\
   3 &  650  &   800   &   650  &    0  &  75   &  800   &    725 \\
   4 &  725  &   800   &   725  &    0  &  37   &  799   &    762 &  -1B \\
\ldots \\
   9 &  795  &   797   &   795  &    0  &   1  &   797   &    796  \\
  10 &  796  &   797   &   796  &    0  &   0  &   796   &    796   &  -1B \\
  11 &  796  &   796   &   796  &    0  &   0  &   796   &    796
\end{array}$$

First column is the generation number, followed by the number of z-lings and b-lings alive for that specific generation. and then the pairing and the offspring.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have not tried the problem, but the hint sounds like it solves your problem.

Comment: You are asked to prove that Z <= 2B. The hint is suggesting that you prove Z <= B since Z <= B means Z <= 2B

Comment: Thanks for the hint , even though i have trouble seeing how the one implies to the other. I mean the end situation ends with z and  b lings at same number always. That is 1:1ratio and not 2:1 for zbling.  Thanks anyway for the help to both of you.

Comment: "At most twice" does not mean "twice". It means "twice _or less_." You are not being asked to prove the ratio is 2:1, rather, you are asked to prove that it is 2:1 or less. 1:1 is less than 2:1 so it is a perfectly OK result.

Comment: "Use a stronger hypothesis" does not mean "use strong induction." You can use the "non-strong" type of induction perfectly well for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Let $z_n$ and $b_n$ be the number of Z-lings and B-lings respectively in generation n.
You are asked to prove that $z_n$ can never be more than $2b_n$
or equivalently that $z_n \leq 2b_n$ for all n.

The hint says to use a stronger hypothesis which would be to prove that $z_n \leq b_n$

Let $S(n)$ be the statement: $z_n \leq b_n$

Base Case: n = 1
  $z_n = 200, b_n = 800 \Rightarrow z_n \leq b_n$
  $S(1)$ is true

Inductive Hypothesis:
  Assume that for some n, $S(j)$ is true for all $1 \leq j \leq n$

Inductive Step: n + 1
  By assumption, $z_n \leq b_n$
  if $z_n = b_n, \,\, z_{n+1} = z_n$ and $b_{n+1} = b_n$

if $z_n \lt b_n$
  $\,\, z_{n+1} = z_n + \lfloor \frac{b_n-z_n}{2} \rfloor$
  $\,\, b_{n+1} = z_n + 2 \lfloor \frac{b_n-z_n}{2} \rfloor$

So, $z_{n+1} \leq b_{n+1}$
  $S(n+1)$ is true

Hence S(n) is true for all n.
Since $z_n \leq b_n$ for all n, $z_n \leq 2b_n$ for all n.